# Spring MVC Multiple URL mappings and multiple Path variables

Tags: spring-mvc

I have an object that I have to display its data in multiple ways.  So, of course I have multiple templates to do that.  However, I now have a controller that has 4 methods that do the exact same thing, only uses a different ModelAndView. I have 2 ways of solving this

1. send in the template name as a URL Param.  (this seems very wrong to me)
2. have 4 controller methods that all call a private method and send a templateName in the method call.  (better, but not best)

is there a way to say, have multiple mappings, that send my ONE method a different path variable?  So mapping "/oneWay" sends the method a String with a value of "templateA" and another mapping "/anotherWay" sends the method a String with a value of "templateB" etc.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your approach 2 seems alright

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the circumstances [URI template patterns](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) might be an option:

```
@RequestMapping("/{theWay}")
public String display(@RPathVariable String theWay, ...) {
  ...
  return theWay;
}
```

Basically it's a combination of your two approaches. If `theWay` should not be the template's name then you can do some mapping.